# Newbie searching for regex

Tags: regex, replace, find, komodo

I am looking for a regex to find as well "right" and "all right" in a text.

I tried:

```
\ball\W+\w+ight\b
```

This only gives as a result "all right", not both "right" and "all right".

Same problem to find both it and its, it's and it is.

Comment: Use `\b(?:all\W+)?\w+ight\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
\b(?:all\s)?right\b
```

This matches `right` and an optional(`?`) `all` + whitespace(`\s`) in front of it, if present.

The [`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) anchors are there to make sure that there is a word boundary before `all` or `right` and after `right`.

Additionally the `?:` is here to not capture the `all\s` group.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/E7UDPT/5/)

**EDIT**

it is / it's:

```
\bit(?:'s|\sis)\b
```

it / its

```
\bit(?:s)?\b
```

Comment: Thanks!! this works well without deleting other words ending "ight". Could you help also with finding its, it is, it's, see question above!

Comment: @DroneStudio i updated my answer with the missing cases. If this solved your question please accept it as the answer!

Comment: fantastic, you saved hours of my time. Where can I accept this as the answer in here?

Comment: @DroneStudio Glad i could help you out :) There is a check mark below the up- and down-vote buttons on the top left of my answer, where you can mark it as the answer!

Comment: sorry to ask: what if i need to delete 3 words: its,  it's, it is - all in one regex?

Comment: @DroneStudio You could do that via `\b(?:it(?:'s|\sis)|it(?:s)?)\b`.

Comment: i see now , just one last question ?: (?:it) means to search anything before?

Comment: No, it means don't match anything (here `anything`) as a separate group: `bla(?:anything)bla`. Check out the top right section of [this](https://regex101.com/r/Q0TAjg/1) page to see the explanation of the RegEx!

Comment: do you mind having a look to my first posted question? The answer seems correct, ((?m)^\*?[A-Z][\w' -]*:\s*),  is it the same language?

Comment: @BoredomOverhead - feeling a real dummy. But i will continue learning step by step. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @DroneStudio yes, it's the same "language" (correct would be search pattern). Yes, keep on learning we all need to start as beginners at some point. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try this \ball\W+\w+ight\b|\w+ight\b
This is a good tool for working with some cases of regex http://rubular.com/

Comment: Thank you Maya, this works well :- . You are a genius :-. And I saved some time:-